# working with two transactions, one seem to work but the other does not. why?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbc, entity

I'm working with two transactions on spring which has reference to two entitymanagers and hence two datasources, while using `@Transactional("transaction1")` it works fine but `@Transactional("transaction2")` throws out an error saying no active transactions found. following is the piece of code:

```
    @Bean(name = "transaction1")
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean2()
                    .getObject());
            return transactionManager;
        }

    @Bean(name = "transaction2")
        public PlatformTransactionManager sermaTransactionManager() {

            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            transactionManager
                    .setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean1()
                            .getObject());

            return transactionManager;
        }
```

respective entitymanagers:

```
    @Bean(name = "entitymanager1")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean1() {

            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource1());
            entityManagerFactoryBean
                    .setPackagesToScan(new String[] { this.environment
                            .getProperty("db.packagesToScan") });
            entityManagerFactoryBean
                    .setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter());

            Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
            jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.level", "INFO");
            jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.parameters", "true");
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);

            return entityManagerFactoryBean;
        }

    @Bean(name = "entitymanager2")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean2() {

            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource2());
            entityManagerFactoryBean
                    .setPackagesToScan(new String[] { this.environment
                            .getProperty("db.packagesToScan") });
            entityManagerFactoryBean
                    .setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter());

            Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
            jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.parameters", "true");
            jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.level", "INFO");
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);

            return entityManagerFactoryBean;
        }
```

respective datasources:

```
@Bean("datasource1")
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource1() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource                        .setDriverClassName(this.environment.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(this.environment.getProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(this.environment
                .getProperty("db.username.abc"));
        dataSource.setPassword(this.environment
                .getProperty("db.password.abc"));

        return dataSource;
    }
@Bean("datasource2")
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource2() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource
                .setDriverClassName(this.environment.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(this.environment.getProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(this.environment.getProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(this.environment.getProperty("db.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }
```

My genericDaoImpl has the following to link respective entitymanagers:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "entitymanager1")
    private EntityManager em1;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entitymanager2")
    private EntityManager em2;
```

when i do @Transactional("transaction1") it works fine, but when i do @Transactional("transaction2") it says no active transactions. and when i dont mention the qualifier for the transactions, error says two transactions found (transaction1, transaction2). any help would be great.

Comment: I believe that you need declare advices in your applicationContext.xml for propagate to the transactions

Comment: transactionManager1 is being passed entityManagerFactoryBean2, is this correct?

Comment: Did you try the config posted bellow? it's working

Comment: @jhadesdev thankx for you response, i followed the way you autowired but both of my transactions seems to have same datasource attached to it. when I autowire the datasource on my daoimpl two different datasources have two different user/password but when i do @Transactional("qualifierName") for both qualifier its getting the same datasource. why would that be? and i made sure the right datasources and entitymanagerfactories are autowired.

Comment: With the JpaTransactionManager, you can only have one active transaction in the service layer at a given time. See the example of method savePlanes bellow. Only changes made with entityManager1 are synchronized with the database inside a method annotated with @Transaction("transactionManager1"). changes made with entityManager2 are ignored (although reads are still executed). I tested this configuration and it works, if you are getting always the same transaction, maybe you are using OpenEntityManagerInView filter in your web.xml, or OpenSessionInView

Comment: OpenEntityManagerInView / OpenSessionInView will search for an entity manager factory with the default name entityManagerFactory, create a entity manager and attach it to the thread. This might be the reason, otherwise can you post examples of the use cases that does not work?

Comment: @jhadesdev i have only one transaction in the service layer.when i do @Transactional("tx1") and getEntitymanager1() it works fine, but when i remove the first transaction and do @Transactional("tx2") and getEntitymanager2() somehow this getEntityManager2() picks up datasource1 which should be picking datasource2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is an issue with the config:**

The problem is that when the beans are initialized like this:

```
transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean2().getObject());
```

The call to `entityManagerFactoryBean2()` will create a new entity manager factory, and then the @Bean annotation will trigger the creation of *another* entity manager factory, with the same config.

When you inject the entity manager factory with `@Autowired`in a bean, you are injecting the instance created with @Bean, and **not** the instance passed to the transaction manager.

**One warning concerning the config:**

The config above allows to do transactions in two separate datasources, but it's not possible with this config to do transactions that span the *two* databases. For example:

```
@Service
public class PlanesService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactory1")
    private EntityManager em1;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactory2")
    private EntityManager em2;


    @Transactional("transactionManager1")
    public Plane savePlanes() {
        F14 f14 = new F14("F14","f14");
        F16 f16 = new F16("F16","f16");

        em1.persist(f14);
        em2.persist(f16);

        return f14;
    }
}
```

This code will only persist f14, because the only entity manager that has an ongoing transaction is em1 (due to `@Transactional("transactionManager1")`). The call to `em2.persist()` will be ignored (em2 can still do reads though).

If you want to do transactions that include *both* databases you need a JTA transaction manager.

**An example of a working config:**

This an example of a configuration that fixes the above injection issues:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourcesConfig {

    @Bean(name = "datasource1")
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource1() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ...
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "datasource2")
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource2() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ...
        return dataSource;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class EntityManagerFactoriesConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("datasource1")
    private DataSource dataSource1;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("datasource2")
    private DataSource dataSource2;


    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory1")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource1);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "your.package.here" });
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ...
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory2")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean2() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource2);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "your.package.here" });
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);
        ...
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}     


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionManagersConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory1")
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory1;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory2")
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory2;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("datasource1")
    private DataSource dataSource1;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("datasource2")
    private DataSource dataSource2;

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager1")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager1() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory1);
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource1);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager2")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager2() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory2);
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource2);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

By splitting the config in several `@Configuration` classes and autowiring them, we ensure that it's always the same beans being used (singletons).

Notice the `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation, that enables @Transactional.

Comment: its a bit late for this to reply @jhadesdev but i ended up using routing datasource for my application. thank you though, you have a very nice explanation, i learnt a lot.